# Adding to a Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array, foreach

Here's my code:

```
$get_access_keys_from_wp = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_tdv_volunteer_positions' );
$new_access_keys = array();    

if ( $get_access_keys_from_wp ) {
            echo "This user is signed up for other positions.";

            $current_access_keys = $get_access_keys_from_wp;

            foreach($current_access_keys as $key => $value) {
                $new_access_keys[] = $value;
            }
            //$new_access_keys[] = $position_post_id;
            $new_access_keys[] = array('position_id' => $position_post_id, 'volunteer_first_name' => $first_name, 'volunteer_last_name' => $last_name);

        } else {
            echo "This user is not signed up for any positions.";

            //$new_access_keys[] = $position_post_id;
            $new_access_keys[] = array('position_id' => $position_post_id, 'volunteer_first_name' => $first_name, 'volunteer_last_name' => $last_name);

        }
```

Initially, I get the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [position_id] => 67
                    [volunteer_first_name] => Mike
                    [volunteer_last_name] => Jackson
                )

        )

)
```

And that's great ... I want it like this. But as you can see by the logic above, I need to be able to loop over the array if it already exists, and add to it so that it looks like the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [position_id] => 67
                    [volunteer_first_name] => Mike
                    [volunteer_last_name] => Jackson
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [position_id] => 68
                    [volunteer_first_name] => Mike
                    [volunteer_last_name] => Jackson
                )

        )

)
```

But instead, I'm getting results like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [position_id] => 67
                            [volunteer_first_name] => Mike
                            [volunteer_last_name] => Jackson
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [position_id] => 68
                    [volunteer_first_name] => Mike
                    [volunteer_last_name] => Jackson
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I don't think that copying `$get_access_keys_from_wp` in `$current_access_keys` is necessary, since you don't seem to modify either afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to go 1 level deeper when adding existing values. Try replacing

```
foreach($current_access_keys as $key => $value) {
    $new_access_keys[] = $value;
}
```

with

```
foreach($current_access_keys as $key => $value) {
    $new_access_keys[] = $value[0];
}
```

or if the existing array contains more than 1 element

```
foreach($current_access_keys as $key => $value) {
    $new_access_keys = array_merge($new_access_keys,$value);
}
```